# PHP script not decoding URL parameters in $_REQUEST[] (%20 values present) after deploying to 5.2.4

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, ssl, web-deployment

I have developed a PHP script that uses $_REQUEST[] superglobal. A typical client request might consist of:

```
http://host.name/socnet/add.php?shortid=1&author=NewUser2&comment=Dad%20dad%20dad
```

This URL is rewritten by Apache in my production environment to an equivalent https:// URL according to the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^socnet/add.php(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/socnet/add.php$1 [R,L]
```

Whilst developing with PHP 5.3.2 and debugging with NetBeans everything works as expected **`$_REQUEST['comment']="Dad dad dad"`**

However when I deployed to my VPS host environment running PHP 5.2.4 and which does the URL rewriting described above **`$_REQUEST['comment']="Dad%20dad%20dad"`**...

**So it looks like `$_REQUEST['comment']` is not url decoded as expected with 5.2.4 and my rewrite rule**

Any ideas for why this is happening and a sensible workaround would be greatly appreciated. Is it a PHP version related issue or something more subtle? Interested to hear from anyone who has encountered this issue at the time of deployment before and how they solved it.

Comment: Fixed it my adding [NE] No Escaping option. See comment (5) on issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34602.

Comment: So rewrite rule becomes `RewriteRule ^socnet/add.php https://%{SERVER_NAME}/socnet/add.php [R,L,QSA,NE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that mod_rewrite is encoding it, leading to it being encoded twice. I have not tried this, but instead of matching (.*), try changing the `[R,L]` to `[R,L,QSA]`. `QSA` stands for query-string-appended.

**EDIT**

The correct option found by landstatic himself is `NE` which stands for no escaping.

Comment: Hi, I tried changing the rewrite rule to: 

`RewriteRule ^socnet/add.php https://%{SERVER_NAME}/socnet/add.php [R,L,QSA]` 

But alas, a quick test in NetBeans reveals: 

`$_REQUEST['comment'] =  Dad%20dad%20dad`

Comment: Fixed it my adding [NE] No Escaping option. See comment (5) on https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34602

Comment: I've added a note to my answer. ;)

Comment: I just had this same issue -- I added a redirect rule to remove `www.` and then some time later started seeing the results of still encoded url characters getting to my server.  It seemed like it was being escaped twice but I couldn't figure out where it was happening.  Adding the `NE` flag fixed it, thanks!